XLS select from .csv file, distinct values
I am am builidng an xls form for student attendance data collection. I am using the pulldata function to pull in the options for selecting students from an external .csv file. However, there are instances where I need to record a school for the child. I have used the pulldata function to access the list of schools from the .csv file, but I need to be able to to select one. Is there a solution to this?
Thanks for any insight!
In the xls form I have created a field "select_one_from_file studentregistration.csv", and added the parameters "value=scl label=scl_name". This will pull in the values, but it does not distinct the school list (there are many, many repeats). I am hoping for a distinct list of schools that I can select one from.
